# Ruby regular expression for asterisks/underscore to strong/em?

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown

As part of a chat app I'm writing, I need to use regular expressions to match asterisks and underscores in chat messages and turn them into `<strong>` and `<em>` tags. Since I'm terrible with regex, I'm really stuck here. Ideally, we would have it set up such that:

- One to three words, but not more, can be marked for strong/em.
- Patterns such as "un*believ*able" would be matched.
- Only one or the other (strong OR em) work within one line.

The above parameters are in order of importance, with only #1 being utterly necessary - the others are just prettiness. The closest I came to anything that worked was:

```
text = text.sub(/\*([(0-9a-zA-Z).*])\*/,'<b>\1<\/b>')
text = text.sub(/_([(0-9a-zA-Z).*])_/,'<i>\1<\/i>')
```

But it obviously doesn't work with any of our params.

It's odd that there's not an example of something similar already out there, given the popularity of using asterisks for bold and whatnot. If there is, I couldn't find it outside of plugins/gems (which won't work for this instance, as I really only need it in in one place in my model). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me you should use a markdown gem.

Comment: I was under the impression that those wouldn't suit for the implementation since it's just in chat, not a forum or CMS. Are there options for specifying what parts of markdown are applicable within those?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you finish what you are doing:

```
sub(/\*(.*)\*/,'<b>\1</b>')
sub(/_(.*)_/,'<i>\1</i>')
```

Comment: You'll want to use the at-least-one non-greedy quantifier (`.+?`) instead of `.*` because the latter will match `*un*believ*` in "so*un*believ*able".  Also gsub() instead of sub() to format *more* than _one_ emphasis tag.

Comment: And what happens when `\1` ends up containing an ampersand?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your criteria are a little strange, but, okay...

It seems that a possible algorithm for this would be to find the number of matches in a message, count them to see if there are less than 4, and then try to perform one set of substitutions.

```
strong_regexp = /\*([^\*]*)\*/
em_regexp = /_([^_]*)_/

def process(input)
  if input ~= strong_regexp && input.match(strong_regexp).size < 4
    input.sub strong_regexp, "<b>\1<\b>"
  elsif input ~= em_regexp && intput.match(em_regexp).size < 4
    input.sub em_regexp, "<i>\1<\i>"
  end
end
```

Your specifications aren't entirely clear, but if you understand this, you can tweak it yourself.